# Replace HTML attribute value inside a string in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a large string with HTML tags which is store in mongodb.
Now I only want replace the `maxlength` value.
Using Jquery It's easy way to do this by `$(string)` you will get html object and before update in database we can use `.html()` but how we can do this in NodeJs.

`<textarea maxlength="20" class="form-control component_label_input" data-component_html="true" data-component_name="attributes" data-component_attribute="script" rows="5">`

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: [Cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio) provides you a similar functionality inside NodeJS.

Comment: Not working for me showing $ is not define.

Comment: what about setAttribute in plain old JavaScript? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp

Answer (score 3):

You can use [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```js
const sample = '<textarea maxlength="20" class="form-control component_label_input" data-component_html="true" data-component_name="attributes" data-component_attribute="script" rows="5">';

const newString = sample.replace(/maxlength="\d+"/, 'maxlength="' + 50 + '"');

console.log(newString);
```

To make it a bit more reusable, you can abstract the login into a function:

```js
function updateMaxlength(elementString, newLength) {
    return elementString.replace(/maxlength="\d+"/, `maxlength="${newLength}"`);
}

const sample = '<textarea maxlength="20" class="form-control component_label_input" data-component_html="true" data-component_name="attributes" data-component_attribute="script" rows="5">';

const newString = updateMaxlength(sample, 50);

console.log(newString);
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy I was thinking the same

Answer (score 0):

```
const str = '<textarea maxlength="20" class="form-control component_label_input" data-component_html="true" data-component_name="attributes" data-component_attribute="script" rows="5">';

const newLength = 100;//or whatever value you want

str = str.replace(/maxlength="[^"]*"/, `maxlength="${newLength}"`);
```

Comment: It's a good practice to explain your code instead of code dumping.